# What kind of US house vote was it that first upheld then struck down the Casey Amendment to Title IX? Can the Speaker always call for a revote?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, civil-rights, procedure, title-ix

Notes to the June 24, 2022 New York Times video [MINK! — My Mom Fought For Title IX, but It Almost Didn’t Happen | Op-Docs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faL6ERtj5oM) end with:

> ...Wendy Mink narrates her mother’s groundbreaking rise to power and the startling collision between the personal and political that momentarily derailed the cause of gender equity in America. After Ms. Mink’s death in 2002, Title IX was officially renamed the Patsy Takemoto Mink Equal Opportunity in Education Act.

After about 16:40 in the video Wendy Mink explains that because of a car accident that she was in, her mother US Representative [Patsy Mink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patsy_Mink) left just before a vote to remove the "Casey Amendment" to [Title IX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_IX) that would have exempted some athletics from equal opportunity protection. Without Mink's vote the motion failed and the Casey exemption stood.

According to the video, it sounds like the next day the Speaker of the House [Carl Albert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Albert) of Oklahoma scheduled another vote:

> ...given my mother's abrupt departure, (Albert) thought about it, considered it, and decided... re-vote. Many on the other side came around, so in the end, 215 to 178 in favor of deleting the Casey Amendment from the Education Appropriations Bill. My mom won, girls and women won, feminists won, yes.

**Question:** What kind of vote was it that first upheld then struck down the Casey Amendment to Title IX? It seems a little odd that the Speaker can call for a re-vote because of an absence, though in this case it did result in a substantial change in voting (on the first vote the Casey Amendment was affirmed 212 to 211).

Can the Speaker call for a re-vote for any type of voting, or is it possible only in certain situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wendy Mink skipped a procedural step. According to the [Daily Digest for 1975](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-CRECB-1975-pt34/pdf/GPO-CRECB-1975-pt34-1.pdf), the votes were technically about Senate amendment 44, which deleted the Casey Amendment from the bill. On July 16, the House voted 212-211 to insist on its disagreement with amendment 44 (page D528). On July 17, the Senate voted 65-29 to further insist on amendment 44 (page D530). On July 18, the House voted 215-178 to withdraw its objection to amendment 44 (page D540).

When the Senate insisted on its position, they noted that the House margin in favor of the Casey Amendment had shrunk dramatically and that it would have been a tie vote if Patsy Mink hadn't had to leave. However, *formally*, this didn't depend on it being a close vote. Formally, what happened is that the House and Senate kept disagreeing with each other until the House finally gave in.